# How to view Comments when viewing Version history?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, version-comments

When I go to `File > Info > Version History`, I can view previous versions of the document without issue.

However, I cannot view comments that were made (and resolved) in previous versions of the document.

when I view Version History via the Word desktop app, this issue does not arise. All previous comment threads are visible.

How can I view historical comments in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to open Word to see them. The comments are stored in the document itself, just like the rest of the document contents.

You can open a previous version of the document through the version history view you mentioned, the comments in the different versions will be from that point in time.

Example below where I have opened three different versions of the same document:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about comments of SPO document version history. You could view its comments like below:

[image]